# Inherit from class with inaccessible abstract members and all constructors inaccessible

Tags: programming-puzzle, c#

The class [`System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar.aspx) of the `mscorlib.dll` assembly is non-nested `public` but its sole instance constructor is `internal` and it also declares some `internal abstract` members.

**The problem:** Write a C# class in your own assembly (code must compile with usual C# compiler) where a class derives from (inherits) the `System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar` of the BCL.

*Your class must have `System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar` as its* ***direct*** *base class.* It is not allowed to have a third class in "between" your class and that class in the inheritance hierarchy.

(Advanced stuff like dynamic assemblies or runtime IL emission is not needed.)

(Stated as a C# problem. Discussions on whether the equivalent problem can be solved in other object-oriented languages too, will also be considered interesting.)

It is not required that the class you write is usable in any way ;-)

Comment: Did not have enough _reputation_ to create tags `encapsulation`, `inheritance`, `access-level`.

Comment: You should come up with an objective winning criteria and post as a code challenge

Comment: @Cruncher Put in code-challenge category. Not sure about winning criterion but I guess the first post to give a valid solution wins.

Comment: -1: no objective winning criterion and changed question fundamentally after a valid answer was given.

Comment: Looks like "first valid answer wins".

Comment: So basically you need this, have no idea how to do it, and hid it as a code golf so we'd do it for you ? :)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre No. It is not useful and I didn't need it. I already had the specific solution Kuhn gave, in mind.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen just teasing :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have either to call a base constructor (which is not accessible) or an other constructor in the same class.

```csharp
public abstract class Class1 : System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar {
    private Class1() : this(1) {}
    private Class1(int i) : this() {}
}
```

So let's call the constructors recursive. Not very useful, but who cares?

Comment: Yes, this was the answer I had in mind. Too bad my original phrasing didn't exclude w0lf's solution, as he was first. I still award the "accepted" check mark to this answer.

Comment: Afaik, you could even intercept the instance with a destructor...

Comment: Will the instance ever be eligible for garbage collection? Do you terminate the thread running in an infinite loop (jumping between the two constructors)? Possibly another way to get an instance is `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Class1))`.

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/10/23/violating-the-smart-enum-pattern-in-c/

Comment: Interesting post. If this cyclic constructor chain hack was new to Jon Skeet, he should have been reading more of your answers at *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* Stack Exchange ;-)

Comment: Under the new Roslyn-based compiler (Visual C# 6) it does not appear to be allowed to have a cyclic `: this(...)` chain of constructors like this.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to inherit a [subclass of `System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.eastasianlunisolarcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```csharp
public class MySubclass : System.Globalization.JapaneseLunisolarCalendar
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var instance = new MySubclass();

        Console.WriteLine(instance is System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar);
        // this prints "True"
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, will have to upvote this because my problem text didn't exclude this solution. However, the intention was to require `EastAsianLunisolarCalendar` to be the *direct* base class. Will update question. Sorry I won't award this question a winner.